# my react native project does not contained any app.xcworkspace file in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to run my react native app. when I run it by Xcode it shows something linker error and solution of that finds running by xcworkspace file.

something happens when I run this by react-native run-ios command

And in my project this file is not there in iOS folder.

react-native version: 0.60.4

Answer (score 1):

## You need to install pod

**Goto ios Directory :** cd ios

> **Run Command :** pod install

Now app.xcworkspace file available in your project ios folder

**if pod file not available then first you need to run init command**

> **Run Command :** pod init
>
> **Run Command :** pod install

Now app.xcworkspace file available in your project ios folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pod files to get .xcworkspace.

Get more help [here](https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to see you error log 
if you are facing **iphoneos" cannot be located** than try  below one line code that will solve your problem

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```